# Making the physics body a certain size and position on the object.(SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am creating a project (fishing Game) that involves a long  line with a hook at the end that is supposed to catch objects(fish) moving across the screen. When the fish collide with hook I want a function to run. However I only want the function to run when the hook is contacted not the rest of the line. The hook is part of the same SKSpriteNode as the line. How can I make the physics body of the line be at the very bottom, so that the function is only called when the fish hit the hook or bottom of the line? I already know how to change the size of the physics body just not the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your line 2 Sprites,  Line and hook,  and have hook be a child of line.  Give each sprite its own physics body, with its own category.  By doing it this way, you can create some neat effects if you use SKPhysicsJoint,  to give it the appearance of a hook dangling from a line.  If you still want to keep it as 1 Sprite,  then when you are creating the Physics Body,  some of the constructors have a center that you can manipulate.  Your other option is you use an SKNode,  add the physics body to that, add this new node to your sprite, and move the node to the hook

Answer (score 1):

When you use `didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` function, you can have `contact.bodyA.node` e `contact.bodyB.node`, the two object involved to the contact, but you have also `contact.contactPoint`, the point where the two object have touched.

About your hook, I've preefer to make two different object:

- the hook ( an `SKShapeNode` with a precise `CGPath`)
- the fishing line

but this is not your case.

So, you have your sprite frame with the properties of origin, size and position. Suppose you have your hook at the bottom of your sprite, near the origin points. When you know that a contact was happened you simply calculate the distance point between the `contact.contactPoint` and the points of your sprite to know what is the shortest distance so what's the part of your fishing line that was involved in this contact.

```
func getDistance(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint)->CGFloat {
    let xDist = (p2.x - p1.x)
    let yDist = (p2.y - p1.y)
    return CGFloat(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)))
}
```

Comment: I have come across issues with SKShapeNodes,  I find it better if these are needed to convert the node to a texture during the loading phase and just using SKSpriteNodes till apple fixes the bugs

Comment: It's a pity that Apple dont yet adjust SKShapeNode library. Do you know some news about iOS 10 , some good news or always the same situation?